# Restrict concurrency in sub-make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, parallel-builds

For a project spread over several sub-directories we use GNU make for the builds. Developers can use the `-j <number>` flag to parallelize the build tasks, and choose a number that suits the hardware of their machines.

However, the Makefiles of a third-party library that we use are not safe to parallelize - they apparently rely on implicit order of targets instead of explicit dependency rules between all dependent targets.

Since I have no desire to fix third-party Makefiles, we currently invoke their Makefiles with an explicit `-j 1` parameter to restrict the number of jobs to 1 for building that library. The rule looks like this:

```
third_party_lib:
    $(MAKE) -j 1 -C $@
```

This works as desired, however, make emits a warning for this:

```
make[1]: warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.
```

which leads me to ask here if there is a better way to restrict the number of parallel jobs in one sub-make.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the `.NOTPARALLEL:` special target to the makefiles which should not be parallelized.

If you don't want to modify those makefiles you can use the `--eval` option on the command line (note `--eval` was added in GNU make 3.82):

```
third_party_lib:
        $(MAKE) --eval .NOTPARALLEL: -C $@
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The documentation states "Any recursively invoked make command will still run recipes in parallel ...", so maybe I have to alter the variable MAKE to include the --eval for this to work. Will test for a while in our Jenkins and locally and get back to this answer.

Comment: Are you saying this suggestion didn't work when you tried it?  I'm not sure I understand your reference to the documentation.  The recursive make will be started and the parent make will configure it to run things in parallel.  The `--eval` will then be run by the recursive make and the `.NOTPARALLEL:` special target will disable parallelism, just as if you'd edited the recursive make's makefile to contain that value.  You most certainly do not want to modify the contents of the `MAKE` variable.

Comment: I am referring to "Any recursively invoked make command will still run recipes in parallel" from https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html, which, I take, means that tasks from third_party_lib/Makefile will only run one at a time, but tasks in Makefiles in sub-directories thereof could again run in parallel. Yes, first tests worked, but then the concurrency error showed up only occasionally, therefore, this needs more test runs to be sure.

Comment: That means that the `.NOTPARALLEL:` option only takes effect for the makefile that it appears in (or in this case, the instance of make which is given the `--eval .NOTPARALLEL:` argument).  So, if the `third_party_lib` makefile is itself recursive then yes, you do need to ensure that all the recursive versions also get that setting.  I don't know if it will work to reset the `MAKE` variable.  You could always create a little shell script `npmake` or something that `exec`'d make with this option, then run that for `third_party_lib`.